# proposedDestinationIndexPath wrong due to header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to set up a table view where I can move rows up and down.
When moving a cell the place in the tableView where room is made for the cell appears to be about 2 rows too high.

When moving a cell I am logging the proposed indexPath through:

```
- (NSIndexPath*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath {
    NSLog(@"%ld", proposedDestinationIndexPath.row);
}
```

and the logged row is indeed about the row I am holding my cell on minus 2.

As it appears, the issue is caused by the table view having a header, which seems to confuse the computation of the proposed index path. The header is added in `viewDidLoad` with a fixed frame, but I cannot compute its height at that time and its size is therefore set in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    //..
    [myHeader setNeedsLayout];
    [myHeader layoutIfNeeded];
    CGRect newFrame = myHeader.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = [self dynamicallyComputeHeight];
    myHeader.frame = newFrame;
}
```

So it looks like the tableView has not fully updated its information about how to compute the indexPath from a visual location, although this does not pop up in other delegate calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reloading your tableView:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    // Add a flag to cehck if it has already been updated 
   if (_hasUpdatedHeaderFrame) { return }
    _hasUpdatedHeaderFrame = YES;

    [myHeader setNeedsLayout];
    [myHeader layoutIfNeeded];
    CGRect newFrame = myHeader.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = [self dynamicallyComputeHeight];
    myHeader.frame = newFrame;

    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: This creates an infinite loop

Comment: @vib Yeah, sorry was late when I wrote this, maybe you should do this once with a flag, I think you don't need to update the header frame everytime viewWillLayoutSubviews gets called over and over ? I have edited the answer

Comment: I could have figured it out myself, sorry. Your answer solves it and it's perfect. Thanks a lot